# Can I access shared preferences (save/edit) from Main Thread?

Tags: android

Total android noob here.

I know you are supposed to move heavy compute / non-trivial execution timed functions to alternative threads. But would editing/saving shared preferences be something to move to an alternative thread off the main one? Or is this a light enough action that it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty light. If there's any doubt, you can use [`SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) which writes to disk asynchronously instead of `commit()` which writes synchronously.

Comment: Its writing an xml document.  If he adds a lot of data it can be heavyweight.  If he's just adding a few variables, yes its quick and I wouldn't worry.